# Angular 8: What is wrong with pipe test?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have to admit, I did more e2e tests than actual component tests, I have sworn to myself to remedy that awful behavior, hopefully making more progress in actually understanding the deep-parts of Angular more. But now I find myself absolutely baffled by a rather simple looking test...

```
import { EuroCurrencyPipe } from './euro-currency.pipe';

describe('EuroCurrencyPipe', () => {
  it('create an instance', () => {
    const pipe = new EuroCurrencyPipe();
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be "100 €"', () => {
    const pipe = new EuroCurrencyPipe();
    const euroSum: string = pipe.transform(100);
    expect(euroSum).toBe('100,00 €');
  });
});
```

Really, all in all NOTHING exciting to see, right? But let's add the pipe in question... it's meant for a German page with no other currencies.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'euroCurrency'
})
export class EuroCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): string {
    return new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', { style: 'currency', currency: 'EUR' }).format(value);
  }
}
```

But when I let the test run it fails with the error message...

```
Expected '100,00 €' to be '100,00 €'.
```

It baffles me... a `euroSum.localeCompare('100,00 €')` results in a 1 instead of an expected 0

What am I missing? It really makes me question what little I already know...

Comment: Just for kicks, change it from `toBe` to `toEqual`

Comment: @Taplar Oh, I did that as well... no dice.

Comment: Yeah, strings are primatives so didn't think it would.  But had to try.  Tis a weird one.

Comment: so what does euroSum evaluate to?

Comment: @WillEvers Well, as the code error message says, '100,00 €' but it is somehow NOT the same as the string it is supposed to be equal to.

Comment: can you add a console.log(euroSum); after the pipe.transform(100); line and tell me what the log message is?

Comment: Ok, so it's something to do with the last two characters of the result.  If I store the result in `var x` in my console and then I `x.slice(0, -2) == '100,00'` I get a true.  If I don't slice or a only slice -1 to leave the space it is false, no matter that I change the second value to appear exactly the same

Comment: The char code of the space from the result is a 160.  The char code for a normal space is 32

Comment: The char code of the `€` from the result and from copy and pasting it into a literal string are both 8364.  So the space looks like it is the culprit.

Comment: @Taplar I can validate what you're saying. And I'm gonna be honest, I didn't see THAT coming. Would you mind writing it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strings are not equal because for some reason the char code of the visible space in the computed result is 160, where as a normal space is 32.  This is why they are not equal.  I cannot explain, myself, why they are different like that, but they are.